# SaltStack: Create a server via salt-cloud and set endpoints autmatically in Azure?

Tags: azure, cloud, salt-stack

I'm a bit stuck with my server deployment recipes...
So far, I can create and provision my servers via commandline:

First I run salt-cloud and afterwards I provision it via salt-ssh...

But since I'm using some special ports (https,...) I also have to set/open input/endpoints (=ports) on Microsoft Azure.

This is where I stuck: is there any way of telling salt-cloud, to automatically execute a script, which opens the endpoints automatically?

My preferred result would be:

1. run salt-cloud => sets up new machine and opens all necessary ports
2. run salt-ssh to provision them

I have already looked at salt orchestration, but it looks like it's more for server fleets, instead of single (external) server configuration.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom bootstrap script that would open the ports that you want.

Answer (score 0):

As Utah_Dave said, I wrote a ruby script to add the ports...

```
# ruby
# execute with ruby startscript.rb
require 'json'
PROVIDER = "yourprovider"
SERVER = "yourserver"

ENDPOINTS = {
  "SSH2" => 17532,
  "HTTPS" => 443,
  "HTTP" => 80,
  "SlangerHTTP" => 8080,
  "Slanger" => 4567,
  "CouchDB" => 5984
}


def get_missing
  service_existing = false
  while !service_existing
    begin
      res = `salt-cloud --out=json -f list_input_endpoints #{PROVIDER} deployment=#{SERVER} service=#{SERVER}`
      result = JSON.parse(res)
      service_existing = true
    rescue => e
      puts e
    end
  end


  existing_services = result[PROVIDER]["azure"].keys
  missung_services = ENDPOINTS.keys - existing_services
end

missung_services = get_missing
while missung_services.any?
  print "#{Time.now} [#{SERVER}] Services missing: #{missung_services.join(", ")}"
  missung_services.each do |m|
    print "."
    `salt-cloud --out=json -f add_input_endpoint #{PROVIDER} name=#{m} port=#{ENDPOINTS[m]}  protocol=tcp deployment=#{SERVER} service=#{SERVER} role=#{SERVER}`
  end
  print "\n"
  missung_services = get_missing
end
```